# Read a CSS file outside a main folder

Tags: html, css, file, asp-classic, stylesheet

I have html file in main(X-folder) which has CSS also, and I convert HTML to asp and i need to put inside a ASP[Y] folder..
My question since my CSS file  is in main folder[X] how can i access on to it. suppose i am in X folder

my problem is that my File in Y folder which is converted to  .asp file when i access its url i lost majority of its image and styles

how can i re-write my css

i tried few; still its not read the CSS

this is an image which describe my problems
[image]

```
<link href="X/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="X/css/responsiveslides.css">
    <link href="X/css/iframeCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a leading slash (`/` at the start)? It indicates to load the resource from the root of the web server. For example, with `<link href="/X/css/style.css" ... />` it will load from `example.com/X/css/style.css`.

You could also use `../`, which indicates to load a resource from a directory below (up a level). So if you were in directoy `Y/`, you could do `<link href="../X/css/style.css" ... />` which loads the resource, again, at `example.com/X/css/style.css`.

Answer (score -1):

The stylesheets included in your page are using relative paths.

Specify your stylesheet links with

```
runat=server
```

and prefix them with the virtual web root path

```
 (~)
```

For example :

```
<link href="~/X/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" runat="server" />
```